# Passing Payload values in exec node

Tags: python, exec, alexa-skills-kit, node-red

I want to pass all the message (msg.*) values to an python script via exec node. ... But I don't get it.

I am using node-red-contrib-amazon-echo to control things on a Rasperry Pi. 
(https://i.imgur.com/la4wzso.jpg)
It is working so far. But I couldn't figure out how to pass the message object to the python script.

Could someone explain it to me please? (I don't want to change anything on the message values... I just want to pass them to the python script... all of them.) There must be a simple solution... isn't it?

[{"id":"169c8f28.849ee9","type":"exec","z":"1c665c0a.1cd76c","command":"sudo python3 /home/pi/bob2/alexa_test.py","addpay":true,"append":"device=licht_am_bett","useSpawn":"false","timer":"","oldrc":false,"name":"","x":1050,"y":280,"wires":[[],[],[]]}]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to move all the values you want to `msg.payload`.

I'm not sure how the exec node handles if the value is an array so you may have to make a concatenated string of all the arguments, but this will also depend on how the python script interprets it's arguments